# How to not block making initial connection with python requests?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a server that uses requests to make queries to another server that may or may not be running. If that server is not running, I do not want to block for a long time; I can just handle the error right away. However, the timeout parameter does not seem to apply to the process of making the initial connection.

From the terminal, I run:

```
>>> import time
>>> import requests
>>> t1 = time.time() ; exec("try: requests.get('http://192.168.99.100/', timeout=1.0)\nexcept: pass") ; t2 = time.time() ; t2 - t1
21.00611114501953
```

This takes about 21 seconds and has no dependance on the timeout I give. I also tried using eventlet's timeout, but it turned out the same:

```
>>> import time
>>> import eventlet
>>> requests = eventlet.import_patched('requests')
>>> t1 = time.time() ; exec("try: \n  with eventlet.Timeout(1): requests.get('http://192.168.99.100/')\nexcept: pass") ; t2 = time.time() ; t2 - t1
21.00276017189026
```

The error I am getting for the connection is:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(11, 'Resource temporarily unavailable'))
```

Finally, I am running python under the Windows Subsystem for Linux, which might be working with sockets differently.

Comment: It works for me on OS X. Maybe it is a Windows related issue. As a workaround you could use a thread - so if the request call in the thread hasn't responded within the timeout just continue on the main thread.

Comment: @J.P.Petersen I think that is probably the issue at hand, since WSL is still in the works.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> timeout is not a time limit on the entire response download; rather,
>   an exception is raised if the server has not issued a response for
>   timeout seconds (more precisely, if no bytes have been received on the
>   underlying socket for timeout seconds).

That being said an example using something like polling.

```
import gevent, time
import requests

from gevent import monkey, spawn, sleep
monkey.patch_all() # for working with requests/sockets


do_not_wait = []
print(time.time())

do_not_wait.append(gevent.spawn(requests.get, 'http://192.168.99.100/', timeout=1.0))
do_not_wait.append(gevent.spawn(requests.get, 'http://192.168.99.100/', timeout=1.0))
do_not_wait.append(gevent.spawn(requests.get, 'http://192.168.99.100/', timeout=1.0))

[x.start() for x in do_not_wait]
print(time.time())

while True:
    sleep(1)
    print([x.ready() for x in do_not_wait])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a task manager (like `celery`) then set the timeout on the worker thread. I think `requests` has support for `gevent` not `eventlet` so that may be why you're seeing the same issues using `eventlet`.